# Send Server Message after Track Users Status (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I try to send a Message in a Server. This Server ID is logged in MongoDB and the Channel ID too. But everytime i'll try it, it does not working. Here's my Code:

The Error is the `return console.log` Text

````js
//This is the guildMemberUpdate file
const client = require("../index.js")
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js")
const {RED, GREEN, BLUE} = require("../commands/jsons/colors.json")
const Schema = require("../models/StatusTracker.js")
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async(member) => {
const data = await Schema.findOne({Guild: member.guild.id})
let channel =  member.guild.channels.cache.get(data.Channel)
if(!channel) return console.log("Es wurde kein Channels gefunden");

    if(member.user.presence.status === "offline") {
        let offlineEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(RED)
        .setDescription(member.user.toString() + " ist jetzt offline!")
        .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))

        channel.send(offlineEmbed)
    } else if(member.user.presence.status === "dnd" || member.user.presence.status === "online" || member.user.presence.status === "idle"){
        let onlineEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(GREEN)
        .setDescription(member.user.toString() + " ist jetzt online!")
        .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))

        channel.send(onlineEmbed)
    }
})```

//This is the MongoDB File
  "Guild": "851487615358337065",
  "Channel": "859444321975009290"
````

Comment: Log `data` to the console. What does it return? As a side question, have you attempted fetching the channel instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the `guildMemberUpdate` event, but that only tracks nickname and role changes. The one that you're looking for is `presenceUpdate`. That'll trigger when any user goes offline etc.

Check the docs for more details: [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate)

Note: You'll probably need to enable 'Presence intent' in 'Privileged Gateway Intents' in your bot's settings page for this to work. (https://discord.com/developers/applications)